# PHP / MySQL column with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';

// Quantity query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE locationcode = 'loc1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$row['locationcode']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['product_id']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['amount']."</td>";
     }
} 
else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

The table that I made for the products available consists of the following columns:
- Product ID
- Product Type
- Brand
- Model
- Cost Price
- Selling Price
- Locationcode
- Amount

The stock must be added to a location. If there is already a storage available then it should be added +1.

Comment: You're missing `echo "</tr>"` after echoing the columns.

Comment: What is your question? This code just displays a table, what does it have to do with adding to a location?

Comment: @Barmar that's true, but not an issue. Each `<tr>` will close the previous one and the table will display correctly.

Comment: Do you mean that now you want to alter the stock in the database? In that case, what have you done so far?

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a form for submitting new stock to the database. There are many tutorials on using PHP to implement web forms.